# How to use angular 1.x services to update one component from another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, service, components

So I have a parent component that has a ton of smaller components inside of it. The general idea is that I need one component to take in the data in an input and display it on another component. This is what I have which doesn't quite work, more details on the problem afterwards:

```
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('dataService', function() {
  let data = {
    key1: "",
    key2: "",
    key3: {
      key4: 0,
      key5: 0
    }
  }

  this.getKey1 = function() {
    return data.key1;
  }

  this.updateKey1 = function(str) {
     data.key1 = str;
  }
}

app.component('display', {
  controller: displayController,
  template: '<p>{{ keyOne }}</p>'
});

app.component('input', {
  controller: inputController,
  template: '<input ng-model="$ctrl.key1" ng-change="sendKey1()">'
}

function displayController($scope, dataService) {
  const vm = this;
  const self = $scope;
  vm.$onInit = onInit;
  function onInit() {
    self.keyOne = dataService.getKey1();
  }
}

function inputController($scope, dataService) {
  const vm = this;
  const self = $scope;
  vm.$onInit = onInit;
  function onInit() {
    self.sendKey1 = function() {
      dataService.updateKey1(vm.key1)
  }
}
```

So the update works, but then it doesn't pass it to the display component. If I log the data object after updating it it's correct but it doesn't show up on the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating a string
`data.key1 = str;`
 in the

`let data = {
    key1: "",
    key2: "",
    key3: {
      key4: 0,
      key5: 0
    }
  }`

Angular doesn't bind strings between components, only binds objects.

see here https://plnkr.co/edit/wfwyyGpcMKOSHGFdg2DS?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize']);

app.service('dataService', function() {
  let data = {
    key1: "",
    key2: "",
    key3: {
      key4: 0,
      key5: 0
    }
  }

  this.getData = function() {
    return data;
  }

  this.updateKey1 = function(str) {
    data.key1 = str;
  }
});



app.component('inputc', {
  controller: inputController,
  template: '<input ng-model="$ctrl.key1" ng-change="sendKey1()">'
});

app.component('display', {
  controller: displayController,
  template: '<p>{{ data.key1 }}</p>'
});

function displayController($scope, dataService) {
  const vm = this;
  const self = $scope;
  vm.$onInit = onInit;

  function onInit() {
    self.data = dataService.getData();
  }
}

function inputController($scope, dataService) {
  const vm = this;
  const self = $scope;
  vm.$onInit = onInit;

  function onInit() {
    self.sendKey1 = function() {
      dataService.updateKey1(vm.key1)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- By setting the version to snapshot (available for all modules), you can test with the latest master version -->
    <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <inputc></inputc>
    <display></display>
  </body>
  
  

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [A Tale of Frankenstein and Binding to Service Values in Angular.js](http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/).

Here's the quick summary of what is happening:

1. `displayController` executes `self.keyOne = dataService.getKey1()`. This assigns an empty string to `$scope.keyOne`.
2. In the view, the expression `{{ keyOne }}` watches `$scope.keyOne` for changes. It initially evaluates to `""`, so an empty string is present in the view.
3. `inputController` changes `dataService.data.keyOne` to some value, such as `hello world`.
4. In the view, the expression `{{ keyOne }}` once again evaluates `$scope.keyOne` for changes as part of the digest cycle. **Problem:** `$scope.keyOne` is still an empty string! `displayController` doesn't know to fetch the latest value from `dataService.data.keyOne`.

Luckily, the fix is simple. You just need to get a reference to the `data` object so that you can correctly evaluate `data.keyOne` when watching for changes:

```
app.service('dataService', function() {
  let data = {
    key1: ""
  }

  //Expose the data object
  this.getData = function() {
    return data;
  }
}

app.component('display', {
  controller: displayController,
  //Evaluate the current value of keyOne in the data object
  template: '<p>{{ data.keyOne }}</p>'
});

function displayController($scope, dataService) {
  const vm = this;
  const self = $scope;
  vm.$onInit = onInit;
  function onInit() {
    //Get a static reference to the data object.
    //The data object itself shouldn't change, but its properties will.
    self.data = dataService.getData();
  }
}
```